# NSNotification only NSLog works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

In my Class X I post a Notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:viewController 
                                             selector:@selector(doThis:) 
                                                 name:@"myNotification" 
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil];
```

In my Class Y I recieve it like this:

```
- (void) doThis: (NSNotification *) notification {
NSLog(@"It works.");
[uiTextView resignFirstResponder]; }
```

The console shows the NSLog message but my UITextView does not hide its keyboard.
(In e.g. viewDidLoad the resignFirstResponder/becomeFirstResponder works.)

Is there any special thing I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Conrad says, observers should be added and removed by themselves...

Use the best practice to define the name of the notifications as static constants like follows:

```
static NSString *const kMyNotification = @"myNotification";
```

*Why? because there is a risk that both @"myNotification" might be two different objects and then the notificationName is different and you won't receive the notification. Since I always declare them as static constants I have never had issues with NSNotifications.*

Then use it like this:

To register the observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(doThis:) 
                                             name: kMyNotification 
                                           object: nil];
```

To post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kMyNotification 
                                                    object: nil];
```

To remove the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, in most, but not all, cases, observers should be added and removed by the observer itself, not by a separate object.  (What happens if the observer goes away before the separate object, and fails to have the observer properly removed?  Or vice-versa?  It makes it all too easy to either leak observers or crash on notifications to deallocated objects.)

Anyhow, first thing's first: have you verified that uiTextView is not nil and points at the first responder?  I rather suspect that uiTextView is not what you think it is.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It is nil but it was a bit confusing that I could still type in it. Now I found a solution.